# How do I authenticate users for my Android app?

Tags: android, security, authentication, oauth

I'm working on an Android app for my university. I've worked on a couple of very basic and minor Android projects and PHP projects before and only the PHP ones required any kind of authentication.

For those projects I just used a simple form that sent the password filled to the server which validated the login by checking the password received with the md5 hashed password stored in a database.

I'm assuming that this kind of a setup wouldn't be ideal for my current scenario, though I do not specifically know why (and if someone could tell me why then it would be really helpful)

So, what I really want to ask is, how can is setup and authentication mechanism? On looking up a little, I found that OAuth seems like a good option but I have no clue as in to how would I set up my own OAuth based authentication. Can someone help me out here? Because I've never done such a thing before, and since this is for the university I do not want to take any chances.

Comment: why don't you use an SQL database with columns like "id", "email", "password" and then make a request to allow or deny access to your app? I personally do not see any disadvantages of such approach

Comment: if you need to authenticate a single user for a single app (like admin) you can use sharedPreference, otherwise if you need to authenticate multiple users for a single app you should use database (like SQLite)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me out here? Because I've never done such a thing before, and since this is for the university I do not want to take any chances.

Your Question seems to say that you are doing this work *for* and/or *on behalf of* your University:

- They will have systems for authenticating staff and students as part of their IT systems.
- They *may* also have, or be governed by rules, regulations, even laws about these kinds should be implemented.  Privacy policies, access control policies, and so on.

Before you decide on a technology and strategy for user authentication and authorization, you need to understand what the University uses and requires.  Talk to *them*.

OTOH - if you are doing this work for yourself (e.g. as a project for part of a CS/SE/IT course) in the *hope* the other people at your University will use it, you can mostly ignore the above in the short term.  In the long term though, the rules and regulation your system *might* still apply (especially government privacy laws ... depending on your country) but you can address that if and when you have enough users that it matters.